# Can this C# 4.0 MSSQL 2008 R2 database connection class be improved - EXPERT Question

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, class, c#-4.0, database-connection

This is my general database connection class. I am using this class to execute my queries through website. What would your suggestions about this to improve performance. Thank you.

MSSQL 2008 R2 SP1 - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 , C# 4.0 - ASP.net 4.0

Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DbConnection
/// </summary>
public class DbConnection
{
    public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=myDB;uid=sa;pwd=MYPW;";

    public DbConnection()
    {

    }

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
                DA.Fill(dSet);
            }
            return dSet;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                if (srConnectionString.IndexOf("select Id from tblAspErrors") != -1)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }
    }

    public static void db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) did you identify bottlenecks before tuning performance?

Comment: 2) never-ever write logic in `catch (Exception)`, there should be error handling code

Comment: Furthermore, do not log to the database. If the database becomes overwhelmed with transactions/connections, adding to that burden makes no sense.

Comment: Andrey what do you mean by that ? i am trying to get ideas about this class. also instead of try catch what do you suggest for this class ? wiseguyeh actually since not many errors happening it is not a problem. i rarely get sql error logged in database and fix those when happened.

Comment: i also don't understand why do you vote for close ?

Comment: @monstermmorpg code review is not on topic here. [There is a specific code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks i will post there martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) How are you making sure the strQuery passed in isn't subjected to sql injection?

2.) Use a logging framework like nlog or log4net. This will allow you to easily dictate where to store the error logs (file, email, db) just by using a config file.

your logging would be something like this instead:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.ErrorFormat("strQry: {0}", strQuery);
    log.Error(ex);
}
```

3.) Use SecureString

```
public static SecureString srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=myDB;uid=sa;pwd=MYPW;";
```

4.) How are you going to write the error to the DB if the DB is down? It'll generate an uncaught exception...

Comment: all the queries which made by using this class is written by me not user generated so they are all secure to the sql injection. i am using for user generated queries different method.  db never get down this is what i suppose :D where does this log stored ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you can specify the location of the logs in the config file. It could be a file directory or an email or stored in a database (it could even be a different db than the one for your apps).